# How to split Set<E>?

Tags: java, file, set

I have class Laptops. Inside this class I have 3 parameters "String name, Integer screen, Integer price" I created Set and now I need to split it and compare with price if price over 2000$ write to file if lower write to second file.
This is my method:

```
public void check(Set<Laptops> laptops, File under2000, File over2000){
    try{
        String under2000 = "2000";
        OutputStream under = new FileOutputStream(under2000);
        PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(under);
        Iterator<Laptops> lap = laptops.iterator();
        while (lap.hasNext()){
            lap.next();
            if (laptops.contains(under2000)) {
                printStream.print(lap);
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Nitpick: each instance of your class refers to a *single* laptop, so its name should  be *singular* (ie. `Laptop`)

Comment: While we are on it. You define the same variable (under2000) twice, as a parameter (File) and as a String.

Comment: My set looks like [Asus|14|1100, HP|21|2100, Apple|19|3500]
How can I split("//|") that I will get String s = "Asus", int screen = "14", int price = "1100"?

Comment: Note that you are writing the `Iterator` to the print stream here, rather than a `Laptops` in the stream.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public void check(Set<Laptops> laptops, File under2000file, File over2000file){
    try {
        PrintStream under2000 = new PrintStream(under2000file);
        PrintStream over2000 = new PrintStream(over2000file);
        for(Laptop laptop: laptops) {
           if(laptop.getPrice() < 2000) {
               under2000.println(laptop);
           } else {
               over2000.println(laptop);
           }
        }
        under2000.close();
        over2000.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to split the set with streams:

```
    Set<Laptops> over2000 = laptops.stream().filter(l -> l.getPrice() > 2000).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    Set<Laptops> rest = new HashSet<>(laptops);
    rest.removeAll(over2000);
```

The first part filters all laptops with price over 2000. The rest takes the original set and removes those laptops. Than you can handle each set as you like.

Comment: If you're going to use streams, use them properly: use a partitioningBy collector to build both collections at the same time.